# How to collapse Recyler view When scoll up another Recyler view

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-collapsingtoolbarlayout

I am new to android and i need help can anyone help me with that. I have two recylerview one is Horizontal and second one is Vertical what i want when user scroll vertical one the Horizontal when shrink too small I researched all over the internet but didnt find any idea to that.
Please help me with this Thanks in Advance Pics for reference

[image: This is the Ideal Behaviour]

[image: When User scroll vertical Recylerview]

Answer (score 0):

IMHO, its better if you create that horizontal RecyclerView as one of the vertical RecyclerView items. This way it is part of the vertical RecyclerView and there is no need to collapse or expand it when you scroll the vertical one. You can check [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26245139/2940733) if you do not know how to create a RecyclerView with multiple types